# Cumulative field calculation using Python in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

[image: Table]

I am using the following Python code to sum cumulatively but I need the summation to take place while the other field is equal to 1 and then again start the summation when it's equal to 2. I need the code to loop this until Near_Fid is 128.Please look at the attached Image of the Scenario. I need the code to Sum up thesame way as the field in Cummulative sum in the attached Picture

## Expression box:

```
accumulate(!GRID_CODE!)
```

## Code Block box:

```py
total = 0
def accumulate(increment):
global total
if total:
  total += increment
else:
  total = increment
return total
```

The above code works fine but needs to be modified in order to consider changes in the other field(Near_Fid).

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is too vague.  Do you mean that you need summary counts of each unique value in the other field?  The field calculator is the wrong tool for doing that.  A search cursor that fills a dictionary with the counts and an update cursor to write the counts works better or use the Summary Statistics tool, a join and the field calculator to transfer the Frequency value of the summary to do that.

Comment: In any case, I have no real idea what the calculation is supposed to produce if it did what you described.  For example, what if the other field has some records that are 2 and then those are followed by records with 1 in that field?  Why is 128 the stopping point, and is it a stopping point whenever 128 is reached for any set of records of the other field or does it stop only if it is reached for each unique value of the other field?

Comment: Can you include some records from the table you are trying to run this on showing their initial state and what you want them to be updated to, please?

Comment: i am sorry for being vague. i have just edited above and attached a picture containing a scenario of how i would like this summation to take place. Thank you.

Comment: What is your real goal you want to achieve? E.g. for NEAR_FID = 1 do you need the results 2, 5 and 7 ? Or it is sufficient if you only get the final result 11?

Comment: I would like the code to Sum for Near_Fid=1 and give the result, eg the 11 shown in the attached image. i want it to then start over and sum for Near_Fid = 2 but it must NOT addd on the 11 for Near_Fid =2, it must start over. i would like this code to be flexible and sum For Near_Fid=1 up to 128. an example ofmy  desired result is shown in the attached image as Cumulative Sum

Comment: Are you confined to the field calculator, or are you able to use Python outside of the field calculator?

Comment: As Richard indicated, it sounds like you want the Summary Statistics tool, using Near_Fid as the case field, and Capacity as the statistics field (statistics type = SUM). This will give you the cumulative sum for all values (i.e. not stopping at 128). Is 128 a special stopping point, or do you reference 128 because it happens to be the last number?